# ESLintでVueファイルのエラーを解消できない

Tags: javascript, vue.js, eslint

#### 事象概要

Vue3の環境にESLintを導入した後に、Vueファイルにおいて理解できないエラーが発生しており解消できてないです。
コメント箇所でエラーが出ていたり、特段問題なさそうな箇所でエラーが出ているので、ESLintが出しているエラー内容と実態が合致しないように感じます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

### .eslintrc.json

```
{
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es2021": true
  },
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:vue/vue3-essential",
    "plugin:vue/vue3-strongly-recommended",
    "plugin:vue/vue3-recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"
  ],
  "overrides": [],
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": "latest",
    "sourceType": "module"
  },
  "plugins": ["vue", "@typescript-eslint"],
  "rules": {
    "semi": [2, "always"]
  }
}
```

### package.json

```
{
  "name": "spanish-app-frontend-vue-vite",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vue-tsc --noEmit && vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "lint": "eslint src"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "vue": "^3.2.37",
    "vue-router": "^4.1.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.41.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.41.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^3.1.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^11.0.2",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.12",
    "eslint": "^8.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.6.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.18",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.1",
    "typescript": "^4.6.4",
    "vite": "^3.1.0",
    "vue-tsc": "^0.40.4"
  }
}
```

↓

### 修正後の.eslintrc.json

```
{
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es2021": true
  },
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:vue/vue3-recommended",
    "@vue/eslint-config-typescript/recommended"
  ],
  "overrides": [],
  // "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": "latest",
    "sourceType": "module",
    "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser"
  },
  "plugins": ["vue", "@typescript-eslint"],
  "rules": {
    "semi": [2, "always"]
  }
}
```

### `npx eslint --ext=.vue,.ts .` の実行結果

```
/hogehoge/src/App.vue
  3:3  warning  Require self-closing on Vue.js custom components (<router-view>)  vue/html-self-closing

/hogehoge/src/components/Footer.vue
  1:1  error  Component name "Footer" should always be multi-word  vue/multi-word-component-names

/hogehoge/src/components/Header.vue
  1:1  error  Component name "Header" should always be multi-word  vue/multi-word-component-names

/hogehoge/src/pages/Grammar.vue
  1:1  error  Component name "Grammar" should always be multi-word  vue/multi-word-component-names

/hogehoge/src/pages/Home.vue
  1:1  error  Component name "Home" should always be multi-word  vue/multi-word-component-names

/hogehoge/src/pages/Sentence.vue
  1:1  error  Component name "Sentence" should always be multi-word  vue/multi-word-component-names

/hogehoge/src/pages/Test.vue
  1:1  error  Component name "Test" should always be multi-word  vue/multi-word-component-names

/hogehoge/src/pages/Word.vue
   1:1   error    Component name "Word" should always be multi-word                             vue/multi-word-component-names
   4:7   error    Elements in iteration expect to have 'v-bind:key' directives                  vue/require-v-for-key
   4:36  warning  Expected 1 line break after opening tag (`<li>`), but no line breaks found    vue/singleline-html-element-content-newline
   4:71  warning  Expected 1 line break before closing tag (`</li>`), but no line breaks found  vue/singleline-html-element-content-newline
   9:15  warning  'reactive' is defined but never used                                          @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
  12:11  error    Don't use `String` as a type. Use string instead                              @typescript-eslint/ban-types
  13:11  error    Don't use `String` as a type. Use string instead                              @typescript-eslint/ban-types

✖ 14 problems (10 errors, 4 warnings)
  2 errors and 3 warnings potentially fixable with the `--fix` option.
```

### Sentenct.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li>a</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>
<script setup lang="ts"></script>
<style scoped></style>
```

### Test.vue

```
<template>
  <div>Test</div>
</template>
<script setup lang="ts"></script>
<style scoped></style>
```

Comment: eslintがvue sfcとしてパースできていないようです。eslintのデフォルトではsfcは扱えないので[eslint-plugin-vue](https://eslint.vuejs.org/)が必要になりますが、eslintrc(.eslintrc.jsなど)はどのようになっていますか？できればそのまま掲載ください。存在しないのであればそれを教えてください。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。.eslintrc.jsonを記載しました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
```

をeslintrcに設定されているため、パーサーがすべてのファイルにおいてTypeScriptになってしまっているようです。

Vueのパーサーはコメントでも示したようにeslint-plugin-vueが持っていますので、extendでplugin:@typescript-eslintよりあとにeslint-plugin-vueを読み込むようにすればまず適切にVue側のパーサーが使用されるはずです。
ただし、この時点では当然tsが非tsとしてパースされいてるのでパーサーの指定は必要です。

カスタムパーサーとして指定する場合、[トップレベルではなくparserOptions.parserに指定](https://eslint.vuejs.org/user-guide/#how-to-use-a-custom-parser)します。
また、`plugin:vue/vue3-recommended`は`essential`や`strongly-recommended`を包括しているのでこれらの指定は不要です。

つまり、

```
...
    "extends": [
      "eslint:recommended",
      "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
      "plugin:vue/vue3-recommended"
    ],
    "overrides": [],
    // "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
    "parserOptions": {
      "ecmaVersion": "latest",
      "sourceType": "module",
      "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser"
    },

...
```

のようにすることで最低限動作するようになる（パースエラーにならなくなる）はずです。

また、Vueでtsを使用する場合、 @vue/eslint-config-typescript の利用が推奨されます。これは、適切に上記パーサーの設定と、`@typescript-eslint`ルールの読み込みを行ってくれます。反映させると

```
  extends: [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:vue/vue3-recommended",
    "@vue/eslint-config-typescript/recommended"
  ]
```

ですね。

（なお、[当該configでは@rushstack/eslint-patch/modern-module-resolutionをrequireすることが推奨されています](https://github.com/vuejs/eslint-config-typescript#vueeslint-config-typescript-1)。）

Comment: ご丁寧にありがとうございます！！
修正してみたのですが、状況変わらずで、、package.jsonと修正後の.eslintrc.jsonを追記しました。

Comment: @skkd かわらず、というのはエラーメッセージも変わらずですか？ `npx eslint --ext=.vue,.ts .`などの出力結果もテキストで追記ください。（また、vscodeについては再起動を試しましたか？）

Comment: また、@vue/eslint-config-typescriptを使用しているのであれば`parserOptions.parser`は指定不要です(むしろ通常はしないほうがいいです)

Comment: 出力結果を追記しました、またエラーが出ている1部のファイルも追記しました。

Comment: vscodeの再起動についても実施していますが変わらずといった状況です。

Comment: vue/multi-word-component-names のエラーに関してはメッセージの通り、
ファイル名を複合語に変更したら解消できました。が、componentではなくてpageとしたいので、複合語制約を外したいのが本音です..

Comment: "vue/multi-word-component-names": "off" を追加して解消できました。
一旦、謎のエラーと思っていた事象は解決できています。

Comment: 大変ご丁寧にコメントいただきましてありがとうございます！

Comment: 解決したようでよかったです。ちなみに、たとえばnuxtではpagesなどではこのルールはfwの仕様に競合するのでoverrideで[範囲を絞って無効化](https://github.com/nuxt/eslint-config/blob/8fce580bac9d3e41c0f65173b38f0e265a5e6259/packages/eslint-config/index.js#L131)されていたりします。とはいえ、スタイルガイドでも[コンポーネントにおいては可能であれば外さないのが強く推奨され](https://v3.ja.vuejs.org/style-guide/#%E8%A4%87%E6%95%B0%E5%8D%98%E8%AA%9E%E3%81%AE%E3%82%B3%E3%83%B3%E3%83%9B%E3%82%9A%E3%83%BC%E3%83%8D%E3%83%B3%E3%83%88%E5%90%8D-%E5%BF%85%E9%A0%88)ています。headerやfooterはまんまHTMLの要素と被っているように。

Comment: ありがとうございます、一旦Vueで作った後にNuxtでリプレースしてみようと思っていました！大変勉強になりました！